# PySpark Error using partition over a ranked column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark Dataframes, the first one contains information related to `Events` as follows:

| Id | User_id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-08-15 |
| 2 | 2 | 2020-03-10 |

The second Dataframe contains information related to previous `Purchase` as below:

| Id | User_id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-07-15 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-07-10 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-04-12 |
| 4 | 2 | 2020-02-10 |

What I wondering to know is how to bring the quantity of purchase for each User 90 days prior to Event Date.

The code I'm using is:

```
    (events.join(purchase,
         on = [events.User_id == purchase.User_id,
               events.Date >= purchase.Date],
         how = "left")
   .withColumn('rank_test', rank().over(W.partitionBy(purchase['User_id']).orderBy(col("Date").desc())))
   .withColumn('is90days', when(floor((events["Date"].cast('long') - purchase["Date"].cast('long'))/86400) <= 90, 1).otherwise(0))
   .where(col('is90days') == 1)
   .withColumn('maxPurchase', max('rank_test').over(W.partitionBy(events['ID'])))
   .where(col('rank_test') == col('maxPurchase'))
)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'over'

What I was expecting is a table as follows:

| Id | User_id | Date | qtyPurchasePast90days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-08-15 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2020-03-10 | 1 |

I appreciate your time in helping me!
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code (line 8), Spark is confusing between Python built-in function `max` and [Spark function `max`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.max). And the main reason is that you (and **many many** others) import Spark functions in a not recommended way

```py
# DON'T do this
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
max('rank_test') # 't'

# DO this
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
F.max('rank_test') # Column<'max(rank_test)'>
```

Comment: Saved me again!